# MVC Routes: How it is happning

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a route like  below

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

But I wonder when I type mysite.com/Team/Details,

it goes to Details action of  Team controller.

How it is happning? I dont have any route added for Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That route says it's the "Default" route, which is added by the MVC project template.

It uses a template format, where a keyword is in curly braces.

{controller} = the controller to navigate to.
{action} = the action method being accessed
{id} = an id parameter, which may or may not exist on your url (hence the `id = UrlParameter.Optional`)

So it sees the url `Team/Details` and knows that, by convention, `Team` is your controller and `Details` is your action.

Answer (score 1):

itThe {controller}/{action}/{id} is what makes it happen, so it interprets every url as site/controller/action/id

This line 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

means that no specified controller becomes home, no specified action becomes index and no specified id = "".

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 0):

The comments in that code answer your question, specifically the comment that says "Parameter defaults". Those are just default values, the important part is the "{controller}/{action}/{id}" part. Basically, if you just go to mysite.com without explicitly typing out mysite.com/Home/Index, that rule fills in "Home" for controller and "Index" for the action. Otherwise, if you specify mysite.com/Team/Details it fills in "Team" for controller and "Details" for the action.